# mysql php query sometimes very fast ansd sometimes very very slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have what I think is a complex php mysql query that pulls data from various drupal tables and allows me to output the results via php in a json format.  Sometimes this query is very fast and sometimes it is very slow.  If you goto http://www.serviidb.com/content/data/view/api_access you can see that actual API response time.  The content in database is growing all the time, and this problem is only going to get worse as the database gets bigger.

Sorry forgot to add the server info:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server version: 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log
Protocol version: 10
```

Example of how I am calling query.

```
mysql_query($sqlApiAccess) or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

If someone would like to see the PHP I am using just ask and I will post it.  I have programmed for years, but new to PHP so i am probably doing everything the long way.

I appreciate any and all help, direction or advice anyone can give me.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   node.title AS "name",
   regions.region AS region,
   field_data_field_media_url.field_media_url_value AS url,
   media_type.media_type AS mediaType,
   repositoryType.repositoryType AS resourceType,
   plugins.plugin,
   media_resource_language.language,
   node.nid,
   resolution.resolution,
   (field_data_field_quality.field_quality_rating / 20) AS quality,
   (field_data_field_reliability.field_reliability_rating / 20)
      AS reliability,
   field_data_field_installs.field_installs_value AS installCount
FROM node
   LEFT JOIN field_data_field_region
      ON field_data_field_region.revision_id = node.vid
   LEFT JOIN regions
      ON regions.tid = field_data_field_region.field_region_tid
   LEFT JOIN field_data_field_media_url
      ON field_data_field_media_url.revision_id = node.vid
   LEFT JOIN field_data_field_required_plugin
      ON field_data_field_required_plugin.revision_id = node.vid
   LEFT JOIN field_data_field_source
      ON field_data_field_source.revision_id = node.vid
   LEFT JOIN repositoryType
      ON repositoryType.tid = field_data_field_source.field_source_tid
   LEFT JOIN plugins
      ON plugins.tid =
            field_data_field_required_plugin.field_required_plugin_tid
   LEFT JOIN field_data_field_media_type
      ON field_data_field_media_type.revision_id = node.vid
   LEFT JOIN media_type
      ON media_type.tid =
            field_data_field_media_type.field_media_type_tid
   LEFT JOIN field_data_field_language
      ON field_data_field_language.revision_id = node.vid
   LEFT JOIN media_resource_language
      ON media_resource_language.tid =
            field_data_field_language.field_language_tid
   LEFT JOIN field_data_field_resolution
      ON field_data_field_resolution.revision_id = node.vid
   LEFT JOIN resolution
      ON resolution.tid =
            field_data_field_resolution.field_resolution_tid
   LEFT JOIN field_data_field_quality
      ON field_data_field_quality.revision_id = node.vid
   LEFT JOIN field_data_field_reliability
      ON field_data_field_reliability.revision_id = node.vid
   LEFT JOIN field_data_field_installs
      ON field_data_field_installs.revision_id = node.vid
WHERE     node.status <> 0
   AND node.type = "media"
   AND (node.title LIKE '%%' OR plugins.plugin LIKE '%%')
   AND node.title LIKE '%%'
   AND plugins.plugin LIKE '%%'
   AND media_resource_language.language LIKE '%%'
   AND (regions.region = "worldwide" OR regions.region LIKE '%%')
   AND media_type.media_type = "video"
```

I read that it causes a query to run slow if "Like" is used, so I am looking at a couple of ways to remove the **Like** sections unless there is information in the actual variables.  Below is the way I am currently developing the where section.

```
/** setups up sql variable for searches.
     *
     */
    $sqlregion        = "";
    $sqltitle         = "";


            $sqlregion        = 'and (regions.region = "worldwide" or ';
            $sqlregion        = $sqlregion . 'regions.region like ';
            $sqlregion        = $sqlregion . "'%";
            $sqlregion        = $sqlregion . $region;
            $sqlregion        = $sqlregion . "%')";

    $slqLanguage      = "and media_resource_language.language like '%" . $language . "%'";
    $sqltitleOrPlugin = "and (node.title like '%" . $titleOrPlugin . "%' or plugins.plugin like '%" . $titleOrPlugin . "%')";

    $sqlPlugin        = "and plugins.plugin like '%" . $plugin . "%'";

    $sqltitle         = "and node.title like '%" . $title . "%'";
```

And the Where statement is setup like this.

```
WHERE node.status<>0 and node.type="media" . $sqltitleOrPlugin . $sqltitle .$sqlPlugin . $slqLanguage . $sqlregion;
```

The where variables are actually parameters that third party apps fill to narrow down the data. like so language=en&region=us&title=the&client=test

```
WHERE node.status<>0 
    and node.type="media"
    and (node.title like '%%' or plugins.plugin  like '%%')
    and node.title like '%%'
    and plugins.plugin like '%%'
    and media_resource_language.language like '%%'
    and (regions.region = "worldwide" or regions.region like '%us%') 
    and media_type.media_type ="video"
```

Comment: something that might help is if you at least said if you're using mysql_ mysqli, or PDO (or something else) for your php querying

Comment: `somefield LIKE '%%'` is rather pointless. basically it'd be "where somefield is not null", but prevents the use of indexes.

Comment: also, if you're getting different speeds with the same query/database volume, maybe it's a networking or hardware issue?

Comment: This php API is being accessed all around the world, so that could be causing some of the problems.  But I am getting slow results myself at different times.

Comment: There are far too many variables to be able to say with any certainty why the performance varies. Could be indexes (or lack thereof), query planner weirdness, machine load at the time the query is run, network traffic issues, anything.  I will say this though, it's a huge query that does a lot of LEFT JOINs.  It might be faster if it was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible that MySQL caches your query result. First of all, there is the generic [MySQL query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html). When using the InnoDB storage engine, there also is the [InnoDB buffer pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html). Both caches are able to store SELECT queries **and their results** in-memory, allowing very quick responses.

However, these caches are usually flushed when the data in one of the affected tables is updated (this is done to ensure that MySQL doesn't deliver outdated results). Furthermore, when the maximum cache size is reached, less frequently used results are usually purged from cache.

Your query joins quite a lot of tables and includes a `DISTINCT` statement, so it will probably cause quite an amount of IO; furthermore MySQL may need to use temporary tables in order to build the result (these may be written to disk too occasionally, causing even more IO). So building the first result set will probably take quite some time, while subsequent requests can be answered from the query cache quickly. When the data changes or the buffer size is exhausted, the cached result is flushed from cache, and the next call will be slow again.

You could try tuning the buffer pool configuration parameters (for example by increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, although I'm not really an expert in this), in order to keep your results in-cache for a longer period of time.